# no. of ways to select $15$ teams from $15$ men and $15$ women such that each team consists of a man and a woman

Tags: combinatorics

"Number of ways to select $15$ teams from $15$ men and $15$ women such that each team consists of a man and a woman."

if we keep all the men in a line and make different permutations of women and associate them with the men,,,,,somewhat like having 15 buckets and 15 different fruits to put in them,,,,in this way the answer should be 15! .But the options are 1120,1240,1880,1960

Comment: The answer depends on how you decide if you count different groups of 15 as really different. If you see all 30 people as individuals then it is just the standard question of picking 15 people out of 30 and the genders are a red herring. If on the other hand you say that group A and group B are the same (for the purposes of the question) if both consist of 4 men and 11 women, even if none of the  men in group A  and only 9 of the women in group A are also in group B then the answer is much much smaller.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to indicate what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig    thanks sir for your advice,,i have done ir

Comment: Your answer to the restated question is correct.  There appears to be an error in the answer key.

Answer (score 0):

Total people are 30 and we have to choose 15 by using combinatorics  combination formula ans is 30C15 .for eg let there be 15 boxes in each box u want to place a person .Now the first box has 30 option second has 29 third has 28 .....last has 15 so total options =30*29*28...........*15= 30!/15!

Comment: options are 1120,1240,1880,1960

Comment: sorry ,,i missed a vital part in the question,,i have edited it now.  sorry

Comment: Can tell me the question properly

Comment: Can you tell that how many people are there in one team and are all the men different or same

Comment: i have edited the question ,,thats all i can say,,,

Comment: If you are trying to find the number of ways $15$ teams of $2$ can be formed from $30$ people, you would also have to divide by $2^{15}$ to account for the two orders in the same pair of people could be selected for the same team for each of the $15$ teams.  That said, the question has been changed to $15$ each teams, each consisting of a man and a woman.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 1240 for the first can be selected as 15C1*15C1 second team can be selected by 14C1*14C1 and so on last team can be selected by 1C1*1C1 total ways = 15C15*15C15+14C14*14c14.....1C1*1C1 = 1240

Comment: according to this logic if we have 2 men and 2 women ,,no. of ways would be 2*2+1*1=5. Sir , can u please tell me those 5 combinations?

Comment: For 2 men and 2 women there would 2 teams first team members can be chosen as 2C1*2C1 =4 now there are 1man and 1 woman and we have to make one more team and we have to take both man and woman in the team this has only 1 way so total ways = 4+1=5

Comment: if we take the men as A and B and women as 1 and 2,,the the combinations are (A-1 B-2),(A-2 B-1)

Comment: what are the other three combinations ?

Comment: This the gap between practical and theoretical maths

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  Consider the case of two men and two women.  If the men are $A$ and $B$ and the women are $C$ and $D$, the only possible team combinations are $\{(A, C), (B,D)\}$ and $\{(A,D), (B,C)\}$.

Comment: Sir ,I dont understand. Please can you explain where i went wrong.

Comment: so can anyone confirm me that whether @Abhiraj.M 's logic is correct or not?

Comment: See the answer we get is not the total no of combinations it's just the no ways of selecting 1st team + second team

Comment: In the question you are not asked the total no combination you are just asked combinations of 1st team + second team ......

Comment: @Mamun  This answer is incorrect, as is the answer in the answer key.  Your work is correct.

Comment: No the answer in the answer key is correct

Comment: still u say this .